# Problem with GetKeyState or my code- it is NOT WORKING as intended. [Autohotkey]

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying click on uBlock Origin at top right corner in Chrome Window, and able to do so.

after click, it allows user to ZAP elements of web page, on clicking left mouse button it shows a dialogue box in the bottom right corner [image]

GOAL:
Click on "Create" button when I click Left Mouse Button.

;Code;

```
IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ;;Chrome Window
{
    ;//Search for Dark red pixel(uBlock origin)
    PixelSearch, Px, Py, 1161, 34, 1312, 81, 0x000080, 5, Fast
    if ErrorLevel
        MsgBox, Check code or region.
    else{
            MouseMove,%Px%,%Py%
            Click
            Sleep 200
            MouseMove,-140,340,,R ;;relative to last clicked Position.
            Click
            ;//Only execute line below when "lbutton" is pressed//
            ;;if GetKeyState("Lbutton", "P") = 1 ;;tried this one too
            ;;if GetKeyState("Lbutton", "P") ;;tried without = 1
            if GetKeyState("Lbutton", "T") = 1
            {
                Sleep 800 ;;some time to wait for pop up
                PixelSearch, Pxd, Pyd, 917, 430, 1346, 731, 0x67D5FF, 5, Fast
                if ErrorLevel
                    MsgBox, Check code or region.
                else{
                        MouseMove,%Pxd%,%Pyd%
                        Click
                        return
                }
            }
        }
    return
}
```

Comment: Try GetKeyState without the parameter: if GetKeyState("Lbutton")

Comment: No luck. it did nothing..